# Adding C++ script to objects in Unreal in the same way as Unity?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

I created a SkeletalMesh object in the scene, and in the Editor I added a C++ component, but once I attached it to the SkeletalMesh I can't find out where it is in the Unreal panel. I know it's working, because after I attached the script to the object it prints some simple debug output.

The main reason I want to know where to find my script component is because I want to able to reference the SkeletalMesh the script is attached through the C++ in the same way you can in Unity with C#.

Is there a way I can reference the object my C++ script is attached to and access the SkeletalMesh values through C++?

My code is just a shell right now, but here I commented the places I want to create a reference to the SkeletalMesh and where I want to animate it:

```
#include "Glove.h"


// Sets default values for this component's properties
UGlove::UGlove()
{
    PrimaryComponentTick.bCanEverTick = true;
}


// Called when the game starts
void UGlove::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    // GET SKELETALMESH VALUE HERE SOMEHOW
}


// Called every frame
void UGlove::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

    // ANIMATE SKELETALMESH HERE SOMEHOW
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Referece SkeltaMesh to your script ,there is no way to do it like unity when you attach a script , however there is a way around.

1. Select your SkeltaMesh in the scene
2. Go to detail panel and add your c++ component.
3. Check your detail panel to know where your script live in the tree and who is its parent , if the sketalmesh directly is its parent, this will be too easy, all you need to get the parent component or actor and cast to it , then return value is the thing you looking for if the cast is successful
4. in this example I did for a static mesh . [image: Event begin play assigning the skeltamesh]

But you have to make your variable in the Script public and editable inside blueprint to be able to set them at run time .

I had the same issue but was with blueprint only .

Comment: or you can even do it in reverse way, like accessing the c++ component from direct parent component which is this case your skelta mesh, and just assign directly your skeletamesh to the component you looking during run time

Comment: Can you show me what needs to be done in the C++ in order to assign the mesh?

Comment: Based on my last comment
-Go to your current blueprint where you setup your mesh.

-Call "Set X" from your C++ componenet ,where X is the name of the variable of your mesh.

- then just plug your mesh to it .

do all of that at event begin play, not hard at all.

Comment: I mean I'm new to Unreal, so I'm not sure how to make the variable public to the blueprint in the c++.

Comment: I added another answer, but plz next time make new thread with your question

Answer (score 1):

To access your variable from c++ inside blueprint , you have two ways

`UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
        void SetStaticMesh(your input variable type);`
Then you call this function at your main blueprint to assign the static mesh or skeltaMesh, or whatever type you want.

Other way , you can put UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite) before declaring your variable , and then you should be able to set it directly at blueprint .

This should be in another thread, but I keep the answer here for now.

[Creating Variables in C++ For Use In BP](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Blueprints,_Creating_Variables_in_C%2B%2B_For_Use_In_BP)

Comment: thanks, I was just wondering one more thing about Unreal. Once I have this static mesh variable set how can I access components of the static mesh in C++ like the transform (position & rotation) and skeleton components (bones).

Comment: you have to read the API and understand it , this is the function you want YourComponenet->GetComponentLocation() , something like that.

Unreal engine is c++ api is not easy to learn pretty fast , and use google a lot, those are common questions that already answered many times

Comment: Thanks, I found that I needed to add a header file to even look at the API, but now I'm on the right path.